# React native - Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {A, B, C, D})

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to understand how the management rest in react-native works ... I copy the current situation:

> HomeScreen.js

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { loading: true };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.handleBackPress();
        this.setState({
            loading: true,
        });
        console.log('url');
        return fetch('url')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseJson => {
                this.setState(
                {
                    loading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson.response,
                },
                function() {},
                );
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container style={styles.container}>
                <Content padder>
                <Loader loading={this.state.loading} />
                <View style={styles.lineStyle} />
                //I want to see what's in here
                {this.state.dataSource}
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Text uppercase={false} style={styles.TextStyleWhite}>
                        {item}
                    </Text>
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                />
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

the url responds with this structure:

[image]

and the errors is this:

[image]

How can I recover certain values ('Category' and 'Plans') under the keys ORD01, ORD02, ORD03, FAM00, PEN00 ??

Thank's a lot!

Comment: dataSource is a object. Not array. That's the cause of error.

Comment: @Naveen okkk but inside FlatList I use item, but if I leave {item} it will not show me anything ... how can I handle it? thank you

Comment: item should be empty if you pass your datasource as an object. It must be array

Comment: so maybe inside componentDidMount () I have to divide the response received from fetch (url) in an array? where can I find some examples?

Comment: Your dataSource should start with [ ] not { }.

Comment: see this https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4b3jpf/using_objectkeys_to_turn_a_data_object_into_an/